# Remote Desktop and Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am trying to remote desktop into a server 2012 R2 machine from a Windows 7 SP1 machine.  The error message I get is:

```
Remote Access Cannot Connect
1)  Remote access not enabled
2)  Remote computer turned off
3)  Remote computer not available
```

They are both on the same local network, and within the same domain.  The server 2012 R2 machine is running on Hyper V.  I am able to ping to and from the machine, and I am also able to remote desktop from the machine to another server.

What I have tried so far.
I have obviously turned on Remote Desktop in the System\remote settings area. I also have 10 CAL's installed on the machine.

I have checked and double checked the Firewall settings to make sure they are enabled.

I have port 3389 unblocked for both TCP and UDP in user mode, and also in shadow mode for TCP.  I also tried enabling them by creating my own rules for the port.

I have also tried running the flushDNS command in the cmd prompt.  Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You turned on Remote Desktop in System\Remote Settings... but did you also add your user account or group to the allowed users list?

Comment: If you fully turn off the Windows firewall does it work?  If you RDP to "localhost" on the server itself, does it answer?

Comment: Yes, I added myself, as well as a Group

Comment: Firewall off - still does not work.

Comment: No, it does not respond when I try to connect to local host.

Comment: "it does not respond when I try to connect to local host". IF it doesn't answer at all, then RDP is not enabled properly on the server.

Comment: It is not responding, but in the services it is showing that everything is running.  What would cause it to not be enabled properly?

Comment: The server you're attempting to connect to is on Hyper-V... Do you have to create a port forward on the host OS? I don't know what network configuration your VM has (I don't use Hyper-V but it may be similar to VirtualBox - NAT or Bridged adapter)?

Answer (score 0):

On your Server run this Powershell command

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Windows Remote Management"
```